# Construct martingale with compound Poisson process

Tags: probability, martingales, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

> Let $X_t = \sum _{i=1}^{N_t} Y_i$ and $N_t$ be a Poisson process with
>   intensity $\lambda >0$. Suppose $Y_i$ are i.i.d. random variables
>   independent of $N_t$, having $N(m,\sigma^2)$. Find $\mu>0$ such that
>   $X_t - \mu t$ is a martingale.

My attempt:

First note that the filtration generated by the Poisson counting process only depends on $N_s$.
Therefore, 
$E[X_t - \mu t \mid F_s] = E[X_t\mid N_s] - \mu t$.

Compute:
$E[X_t\mid N_s] = E[\sum _{i=1}^{N_t} Y_i\mid N_s] = E[\sum _{i=1}^{N_s} Y_i+ \sum _{i=N_{s+1}}^{N_t} Y_i\mid N_s]=N_s E[Y_1]+E[\sum _{i=N_{s+1}}^{N_t} Y_i\mid N_s]$

With the memoryless property, the second term is the expression above can be written as:
$$E[\sum _{i=N_{s+1}}^{N_t} Y_i\mid N_s] = E[\sum _{i=1}^{N_{t-s}} Y_i]=E[E\sum _{i=1}^{N_{t-s}} Y_i\mid N_{t-s}]]=E[N_{t-s} m]=\lambda (t-s) m$$

Therefore, 
$E[X_t-\mu t|N_s] = N_s m + \lambda(t-s)m - \mu t = N_s m + E[X_t] - E[X_s] - \mu t$.

How can I relate the above expression to $X_s$ so that I can choose $\mu$ to ensure the martingale condition? Are there any mistakes in the above computation?

Comment: $E(X_t)=\lambda t m=\mu t$, hence $\mu=\lambda m$

Comment: @A.S. I agree that $E[X_t] = \lambda t m$. But why must we not compute a conditional expectation here?

Comment: It's equivalent. You need to show $E(X_t-X_s|X_s)=E(X_t-X_s)=\mu(t-s)$. But $X_t-X_s\sim X_{t-s}$.

Comment: @A.S. Thanks. Is there anything wrong with my approach. Is it just harder to see it that way?

Comment: You need to condition on $X_s$, not $N_s$. Overall, start thinking about these processes in terms of independent increments - which simplifies many computations.

Comment: question is not clear@Kerry